# How does one stop search engines from querying site somewhat private directories?

Tags: search, seo, web-crawler

I'm getting some directories queried on Google, Bing, etc. that I don't necessarily want the world to see. How can I prevent it from crawling these pages/directories? Also how do I remove previous entries?

Comment: If you don't want the world to see them; then why are you publishing these "private" pages in the first place? A robots.txt will stop a search engine from indexing content, but not an average hacker.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, the question was referring to only search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *friendly* web crawlers (Google, Bing, Yahoo, Baidu, etc.) will respect your [`robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/). An example from the very helpful http://www.robotstxt.org/:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```

Of course, if you *really* want to restrict your private content, you'd be better served by using your webserver's [authentication and authorization tools](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) or [restrict access by address](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

Comment: +1 for mentioning server security tools. A robots.txt will not magically ward of malicious attackers

Answer (score 1):

Most search engines first check for a [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file before they start crawling your site. If don't want it to crawl certain directories, create a `robots.txt` file in your root directory and add this to it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my_private_dir
```

If you want an example `robots.txt` file, [here is stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt).